# Scroll to specific div on another section when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a website, which has 4 pages within the same index file, out of which only one page is active at a time. I have 3 links in my home page. I need to scroll to a particular div in another page, when i click on homepage links. I tried to implement this, but instead of scrolling to specific div, its just showing the section only.

Comment: The href attribute of the links should be pointing to the id of the div you wish to scroll to.

Comment: Is your question regarding the issue that it is not scrolling or that it is not scrolling animatedly, as in you can't see it scrolling ?

Comment: @jijishthomas did you check the answer

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for something like this , Run with snippet full screen , and check is this what you need

```css
body {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
 
}
.common {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 height: 100vh;
 display: table;
}
.allbody {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}

a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 15px;
}
header {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #fff;
}
.common h2 {
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10%;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
#firstDestination {
 background: #000;
}
#secondDestination {
 background: #999;
}
#thirdDestination {
 background: #ccc;
}
#fourthDestination {
 background: #c1c1c1;
}
```

```html
<body>

 
<header>
 <a href="#firstDestination">first page</a>
 <a href="#secondDestination" >second page</a>
 <a href="#thirdDestination">third page</a>
 <a href="#fourthDestination">fourth page</a>
</header>


<div class="allbody">
 <div class="common" id="firstDestination" ><h2>First Page</h2></div>
 <div class="common" id="secondDestination"><h2>Second Page</h2></div>
 <div class="common" id="thirdDestination" ><h2>Third Page</h2></div>
 <div class="common" id="fourthDestination" ><h2>Fourth Page</h2></div> 

</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function isElementInViewport (el) {
      //special bonus for those using jQuery
      if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
      }
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
      );
    }


    // click-to-scroll behavior
    $("a").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var section = this.href;
      var sectionClean = section.substring(section.indexOf("#"));
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionClean).offset().top
      }, 1000, function () {
        window.location.hash = sectionClean;
      });
    });
    
    // listen for the scroll event
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
      //console.log("onscroll event fired...");
      // check if the anchor elements are visible
      $(".common").each(function (idx, el) {
        if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
          // update the URL hash
          if (window.history.pushState) {
            var urlHash = "#" + $(el).attr("id");
   window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
          }
        }
      });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery

```
$("#link").click(function(){   //id of the link which is being clicked
      $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#div").offset().top   //id of div to be scrolled
      }, 1000);
});
```

when you click a link the section with div is scrolled to top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jQuery.animate` function and use the `scrolltop` property.

I have written down an example for you.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.div {
  min-height: 1100px;
  background: red;
}
#myDiv {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">button</div>
<div class="div">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has
    a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search
    for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random
    text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
    Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
    written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has
    a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search
    for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random
    text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
    Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
    written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has
    a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search
    for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random
    text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
    Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
    written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has
    a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search
    for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random
    text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
    Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
    written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

</div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```